# How to get part of URL current?

Tags: javascript, php, html

My Url looks like: http://google.com/stackoverflow/post/1

Now, I want to get just part of URL: http://google.com/stackoverflow/ and add it to code:

Post . How to do it ? Thanks !

Comment: In what language? There are many ways to do it. You can look for the 4th slash, or for "overflow/" and get a substring of everything up to there. Or you can use regular expressions. Look up those functions (google 'string functions' and 'php' or 'javascript') and try to figure it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the full URL in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php) -- this, plus a little basic string manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED:

Using JavaScript:

```
var url = "http://google.com/stackoverflow/post/1";    // or var url = window.location;

var matches = url.match(/^http\:\/\/([\w\.]+)\/(\w+)\/.+/);

if( matches ){
    var newURL = "http://" + matches[1] + "/" + matches[2] + "/";
    alert( newURL );
}

document.getElementById('post_link').href = newURL;
```

HTML:

```
<a id="post_link">post</a>
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDHGM/4/)

Comment: Thanks ! It works perfectly. However, can you show me how to add javascript variable to html code ? < a href="">post</a>

Comment: <head><script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {   .... JavaScript here ... }; </script></head>

Comment: No, I mean how to add to html code to make it: < a href="http://google.com/stackoverflow/">post</a> ?

Comment: document.getElementById('post_link').href = newURL;

Answer (score 2):

Plz try this:

```
var url = "http://google.com/stackoverflow/post/1";
var partOfUrl = url.split('post')[0];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use location Object

```
location.href
location.pathname
```